# Связь Access с сервером MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, access

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые!
Задали нам в магистратуре непутёвое задание.. Разработать ,базу данных, серверная часть которой хранится на MS SQL Server, а клиент в Access. Серверная часть была мной разработана со всем необходимым: триггеры, хранимые процедуры, записи в таблицах и так далее.
Далее возникает проблема.. В Access при создании связи с базой данных можно проследить количество записей, НО содержимое каждой ячейки заменено на запись #Удалено.. Не могу разобраться в данной проблеме, прошу вашей помощи..
Прилагаю содержание таблицы, находящейся на сервере,[Таблица на сервере (MS SQL Server) http://rgho.st/7VSHvmL5j/image.png](http://rgho.st/7VSHvmL5j/image.png) и на клиенте [Таблица на клиенте (Access) http://rgho.st/7FskQW5Cf/image.png](http://rgho.st/7FskQW5Cf/image.png)
Очень надеюсь на помощь в данном вопросе. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А Client_ID у вас auto_increment? И какого типа этот столбец?

Comment: Client_ID первичный ключ, bigint, заполняется автоматически

Comment: На просторах Интернета я нашел то, что, вероятно, это bigint мешает т.к. в Access нет настолько большого значения. (http://www.sql.ru/forum/658642/problema-pri-svyazyvanii-tablic-cherez-odbc)